# "translation missing" in simple_captcha

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, captcha

I have some sort of error that when you view [this page](http://community.whatyoutheat.com/pins/new), in the box where you enter captchas, it says "translation missing." I've looked around and noticed it may have something to do with i18n or flashes, but I am not sure, and nothing I've found regarding those two thus far has worked. Anyone able to lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following to your app's translation files (For example myapp/config/locales/en.yml):

```
en:
  simple_captcha:
    placeholder: "Enter the image value"
    label: "Enter the code in the box:"
    message:
      default: "Secret Code did not match with the Image"
      user: "The secret Image and code were different"
```

From the documentation here:

https://github.com/pludoni/simple-captcha#i18n

For more information on rails internationalisation (i18n):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Answer (score 1):

Set the attributes directly in the view:

```
<%= f.simple_captcha(:label => "", :placeholder => "Enter text", :refresh_button_text => "Refresh text") %>
```